# Plot.ly does not render when passed an array of traces

Tags: javascript, plotly

The code below fails to render data. No exceptions are thrown. However, the same code does work when given only one of the two traces as shown in the second code segment. The only difference is calling

```
    Plotly.newPlot(target_target, traces); // doesn't render
```

instead of:

```
    Plotly.newPlot(target_target, trace0); // trace1 also works.
```

I'm a javascript noob so it's probably something wrong with my *traces* array, but it looks like the example code I looked at.

Code that doesn't work (complete):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='target' style="width:600px;height:450px;"></div>
    <script>
        var target_target = document.getElementById('target');

        var trace0 =
            [{
                x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                y: [0.5, 1.5, 6.5, 14.5, 25.5, 39.5],
                type: 'scatter'
         }];

        var trace1 =
            [{
                x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                y: [0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 14.0, 25.0, 39.0],
                type: 'scatter'
         }];

    var traces = [ trace0, trace1 ];
    Plotly.newPlot(target_target, traces);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code that does work (complete):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='target' style="width:600px;height:450px;"></div>
    <script>
        var target_target = document.getElementById('target');

        var trace1 =
            [{
                x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                y: [0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 14.0, 25.0, 39.0],
                type: 'scatter'
         }];

    Plotly.newPlot(target_target, trace1);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made was simply that the individual traces should be `objects` not `array of a single object`, all you need to do is to make this correction.

**Before:**

```
var trace0 =
            [{
                x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                y: [0.5, 1.5, 6.5, 14.5, 25.5, 39.5],
                type: 'scatter'
         }];
```

**After:**

```
var trace0 =
            {
                x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                y: [0.5, 1.5, 6.5, 14.5, 25.5, 39.5],
                type: 'scatter'
         };
```

Then these individual traces(objects) need to be grouped into an array and set in plotly.

```
var traces = [ trace0, trace1 ];
Plotly.newPlot(target_target, traces);
```

That is why the second example works, since the traces are received as an array of objects.

Please do refer the below example and check if your issue is resolved!

```js
var target_target = document.getElementById('target');

var trace0 = {
  x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
  y: [0.5, 1.5, 6.5, 14.5, 25.5, 39.5],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace1 = {
  x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
  y: [0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 14.0, 25.0, 39.0],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var traces = [trace0, trace1];
Plotly.newPlot(target_target, traces);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='target' style="width:600px;height:450px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```